# Drivers do not appear in graph editor

Tags: drivers

I am attempting to create a driver to change the color of a material. However, after creating the material, I cannot find it in the graph editor.  I have the object selected that has the material, and I also tried deselecting the Arrow Button that forces only selected items to be displayed.

Also, if I create a driver for a different object, say a cube's position, the drivers will still not appear.  Creating a new document fixes this issue.

Comment: Please add a screen shot, showing the purple field of the driver you've added and your graph editor in driver mode.

Comment: Are you using Drivers mode (https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZcRm.png)?

Comment: Sometime the properties of a given object do not update right away in the UI, try deselecting and reselecting the object in question (you will need the graph editor open though, and be in driver mode) the specific property that you have added a driver to should now show up in the tree to the left.